# Is Travis CI integrated with JIRA?

Tags: jenkins, plugins, continuous-integration, jira, travis-ci

I am looking for CI which is integrated with JIRA. I found some good stuff for Jenkins but not for Travis CI.

Is any plugin is available for Travis CI - JIRA integration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know if it would help but Atlassian got their own stuff: [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo).